# Lead Forensics: Does it load synchronously? Integrating with Google Tag Manager

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm troubleshooting why my GTM Custom HTML Tag for Lead Forensics (LF) isn't being reported back in the LF Visitors List.
GTM only supports asynchronously loading tags, so I think that is the problem.

Here is the tracking code, if that helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bux1lXXXX.com/js/XXXXX.js"></script>
<noscript><img src="http://bux1lXXXX.com/XXXXX.png" style="display:none;" /></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more details about what "isn't working"? If you right click, select "Inspect Element", select the "Console" tab and then copy paste any errors you see there into your question that would help.

Also, is XXXXX.js something you wrote? What does it do?

Since you mentioned asynchronously loading, have you tried adding the async attribute to the script tag like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bux1lXXXX.com/js/XXXXX.js" async></script>
```

Comment: I haven't taken a look at the XXXXX.js file took much in depth, but it is hosted by Lead Forensics (I didn't create it). I'll post more details about the Javascript file and remove any PII. Anyway, lots of clever tips I haven't tried yet. Will give them a try soon and post the results. Really appreciate the ideas.